# Splitting objects into groups of 0 or more

Tags: combinations

You have *g* groups and *o* object. Determine a formula to calculate all possibilities. For example, if we set *g* = 3 and *o* = 3 we should get 10.

3 0 0

0 3 0

0 0 3

2 1 0

2 0 1

1 2 0

1 0 2

1 1 1

0 1 2

0 2 1

I came to this answer by brute force counting all the possibilities, but do not understand how to generate a general formula if there even is one. A group of 0 doesn't make sense, but I am including them to see how they would be accounted for.

Comment: Based on your brute force list, you seem to be reaching for $\binom{p+t-1}{t-1}$.  For your example $\binom{3+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{5}{2}=10$.  That said, this is a bizarre interpretation of your problem's wording as people are almost always considered to be distinct and teams often require at least one person on them to be viable.

Comment: For your interpretation, see [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: For the problem as I would have interpreted it, people distinct, teams labeled, teams must have at least one member each, the answer would be $t!{p\brace t}$ where the curly brackets are in reference to [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: The specific scenario is difficult to describe but the possibility of there being 0 people in a team is possible for my problem

Comment: Then your question is equivalent to solving $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$ in non-negative integers, which, as @peterwhy notes, is readily solved using stars and bars.

Comment: I reworded the question to better convey it for future viewers, but it seems like the star and bars thing answer it. Thank you.